# Practical Javascript Challenges

Tags: javascript

So I have the basics of Javascript down, but now I'm looking for resources that challenge me to do some common JS-based tasks AND PROVIDE EXAMPLES. The examples are crucial, otherwise I'm just shooting in the dark. I realize I could look at websites that implement JS, but I don't feel quite confident enough to parse through code on fully implemented websites. I'm looking more for things like stand-alone calculators and simple text based games, etc. I'm aware of CodeAcademy and have done their challenges, but at this point I find their challenges to be too guided and simple; I need something that more strongly exercises and strengthens my programming problem solving skills.

Comment: Sorry, this type of question does not belong here. Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: What's the question? If you want to program a calculator or a game to test your skills, just do it!

Answer (score 1):

Make the Windows 7 UI in Javascript Complete with Window Previews :p